# Kendo Grid Infinite Scrolling Not Requesting With Correct ParameterMap (Page, Skip)?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, infinite-scroll

I'm currently trying the kendo grid virtualization/infinite scrolling on my project but i cannot make it working properly(it does work but incorrect behavior).

The problem i encounter is that the request to the backend service especially the parameterMap page and skip is acting strange here is the scenario

Assume i have 50 data on my database, the correct behavior would be

1. first load will be page = 1, skip 0, pageSize=20, take =20
2. second load will be page = 2, skip = 20, pageSize = 20, take = 20
3. third load will be page = 3, skip = 40, pageSize = 20, take = 20

Instead it was

1. first load will be page = 1, skip 0, pageSize=20, take =20
2. second load will be page = 1, skip 0, pageSize=20, take =20
3. third load will be page = 2, skip = 20, pageSize = 20, take = 20

***It is not loading the remaining 10 data, previously it is even stranger where it jump from page 1 to 3 before i applied the limitation requirement***

i have look into the limitation of the feature as stated on [kendo doc's here.](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/appearance#limitations-of-virtual-scrolling)

1. I tried to make the  height consistant
2. I set server paging to false
3. i set the pageSize more than 3times the visible data on the view which is 6 data at max, so i set it to pageSize = 20

But to no avail

This is my datasource code which is custom

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: function (options) {
                var ajaxParam = {
                    url: Const.url,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: customParameterMap(dataSource),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (result) {
                        options.success(result);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        options.error(result);
                    }
                };
                invokeSecuredRESTRequest(loadUserLogin().userName, ajaxParam);
            }
        },
        schema: {
            model: _model,
            parse: function (response) {
                var parser = dataSource.parser;

                if (typeof parser === "function") {
                    var newResponse = parser(response);

                    return newResponse;
                } else {
                    return response;
                }
            },
            data: "data",
            total: "total"
        },
        error: function(e) {
            var msg = e.xhr.responseText;
            alert(msg);
        },
        requestEnd: function(){
            if (gridTarget) {
                kendo.ui.progress(gridTarget, false);
            }
        },
        serverFiltering: true,
        serverSorting: true,
        serverPaging: false,
        pageSize: 20
    });
    dataSource.setGridTarget = function(target){
        gridTarget = target;
        kendo.ui.progress(gridTarget, true);
    };
    dataSource.showProgress = function(isShowProgress) {
        if (gridTarget) {
            kendo.ui.progress(gridTarget, isShowProgress);
        }
    };
    return dataSource;
};
```

And here is my html and the template for the grid

```
<div id="scr-inbox-01-list"
     data-role="grid"
     data-columns="[{ 'field': 'fullName', 'width': 270, headerAttributes: {style: 'display: none'}}]"
     data-row-template="grid-template"
     data-auto-bind="false"
     data-selectable="trueSelectable"
     data-scrollable="{ virtual: true }"
     data-bind="source: dataSource, events: { change: onChange, dataBound: onDataBound}"
     style="min-height: 998px; height: 998px; box-sizing: border-box;overflow: hidden;list-style: none;padding-left: 0; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
</div>
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="grid-template">
<tr style="height:50px">
   <td>
      <div> #: firstName #</div>
      <div> #: lastName #</div>
   </td>
</tr>
</script>
```

EDIT : i'm adding my customParameterMap

```
var customMrParameterMap = function (param, anotherParam) {
var params = {
    take: param.take(),
    skip: param.skip(),
    page: param.page(),
    pageSize: param.pageSize(),
    sort: kendo.stringify(param._sort),
    filter: kendo.stringify(param._filter),
    group: param._group,
    aggregate: param._aggregate
};
var _anotherParam = anotherParam || null;
return param.options.serverPaging || param.options.serverFiltering || param.options.serverSorting ? params : _anotherParam;
};
```

If anyone have any idea what might causing this to happen please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

I finaly found out that my custom parametermap and the way i use the `data: customParameterMap(dataSource)` to pass on the filter, page, take, skip, and sort somehow broke the endless scrolling behavior (tough i dont know exactly why). Instead just do the passing on the read function directly.

```
transport: {
   dataType: "json",
       read: function(options) {
          param = {};
          param.page = options.data.page;
          param.take = options.data.take;
          param.skip = options.data.skip;
          param.pageSize = options.data.pageSize;
          if(options.data.sort) param.sort = JSON.stringify(options.data.sort);
          if(options.data.filter) param.filter =  JSON.stringify(options.data.filter);
          var success = function(result){
              options.success(result);
          }
          var error = function(result){
              options.error(result);
          }
          var url = Const.Url;
                Rest.get(url,param,success,error);
      }
}
```